# How can content-encoding be ignored

Tags: javascript, ajax, content-encoding

I have a device I need to download a file from.  In certain cases, the file may have an incorrect `content-encoding`.  Particularly, it may have a content-encoding of "gzip", when it is not gzipped, or compressed in any way.

So, when the file is gzipped, it's simple to get the content using a basic ajax GET:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://' + IP + '/test.txt',
    type: 'GET'
})
.done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

But this fails, as you might expect, when the content-encoding is wrong.

To be clear, I'm not looking for a solution to bypass the `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` when simply navigating to the given url in a browser.  I want to be able to load, for instance, a csv, into a string in javascript for further parsing.

Can I GET the file, and force it to skip attempting decoding, or override the content-encoding of the response, or some such?

Comment: I would suggest trying to remove gzip from the Accept-Encoding header, but it looks like browsers won't let you do that for some reason. Only thing I can think of is a proxy where you have some server code make that request, which should give you more flexibility in how to build the request and process the response.

Comment: Reasonable thought with the `Accept-Encoding`, but already gave it a go, and confirmed that it will *always* send back `Content-Encoding: gzip`, regardless.

Comment: My only other thought then would be to either yell at (or buy cookies for) the people responsible for sending the wrong response header, and get them to fix it.

Comment: Could always just create a server side solution to handle grabbing the text and return it.

Comment: is a try-catch too simple to use here? i think that would work, and catch the expected error of when the encoding is incorrect.

Comment: might be able to use YQL to pull in the CSV, if it doesn't get choked up like the browser does...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is simply not possible to do via client-side JavaScript, per the WHATWG's [XHR spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org), which makes use of the *fetch* operation from the WHATWG [Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org).

Client-side scripts can only read the response object supplied by the browser environment. The Fetch Standard defines how the browser environment must build a response object's *body* attribute in step 2 of the *fetch* operation (note especially substeps 2 through 4):

> 2. Whenever one or more bytes are transmitted, let *bytes* be the transmitted bytes and run these subsubsteps:
>
>    1. Increase response's body's transmitted with *bytes*' length.
>    2. Let *codings* be the result of parsing `Content-Encoding` in response's header list.
>    3. Set *bytes* to the result of handling content codings given *codings* and *bytes*.
>    4. Push *bytes* to response's body.

Where the action *handling content codings* is:

> To **handle content codings** given *codings* and *bytes*, run these substeps:
>
> 1. If codings are not supported, return *bytes*.
> 2. Return the result of decoding bytes with the given *codings* as explained in HTTP.

From this definition, we can see that a response object never exposes encoded bytes in its *body* property. Before bytes can be added to the body, they must first be decoded. A client script *never* has access to what the spec calls "transmitted bytes" (i.e., the actual encoded bytes sent over the wire).

Decoding is determined exclusively by the `Content-Encoding` header. There is no mechanism by which client-side JavaScript can manipulate the response headers of a response object, so `Content-Encoding` must be whatever the server originally sent.

What your server is doing is wrong. Your only options are:

1. Fix the behavior of the server.
2. Run the HTTP response through a proxy that fixes the `Content-Encoding` response header before it reaches your client.

Answer (score 2):

In a modern browser-based environment, you can't alter the Accept-Encoding, thanks to the Same-Origin policy for HttpRequest:

[Link to Google's explanation](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_XMLHttpRequest)

For your brain-dead device, the best workaround is a server-side proxy that fetches the content and ignores the incorrect encoding, and then returns the results with a sane set of headers.